# Speed up recursively listing FTP files

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have an Android app that lists folders and files of a [FTP directory](http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/download.mapsforge.org/maps/). I use 
[Apache Commons FTP Client](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/). It comes down to this line which I call for every folder

```
FTPFile[] folderElements = ftpClient.listFiles(folderName);
```

Works fine but is very time consuming. The whole task (getting all files and folders) takes about a minute. Can I speed that up somehow?

I already tried

```
ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024000);
```

Comment: The only way to speed it up, is using multiple parallel connections.

Comment: Does one call take a minute?

Comment: No: *The whole task (getting all files and folders) takes about a minute*

Comment: What's the purpose of your bounty? Do you expect some new approach (apart from parallelization as suggested already)? Or do you expect someone to code it for you?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Every bounty has a description. So does mine. And I don't expect anything in particular.

Comment: Is  the FTP directory on the mobile device?

Comment: No, on a server.

Answer (score 2):

my project might be a help.
https://github.com/Honwhy/commons-pool-ftp (see ftpcp branch)

```
FTPCPManager ftpCPManager = new FTPCPManager();
ftpCPManager.setUrl("ftp://127.0.0.1");
ftpCPManager.setUsername("sa");
ftpCPManager.setPassword("sa");
ftpCPManager.setKeepAliveTimeout(1 * 60);

ftpCPManager.setConnectTimeout(1 * 1000);
ftpCPManager.setMaxWait(1 * 1000);

CommonFAOSupport support = new CommonFAOSupport(ftpCPManager);

support.downloadDirectory("/apps/data/ftp/download", 4000, 10, processService); //10 thread
```